# How do I add an intent-filter to a Flex android project manifest?

Tags: java, android, apache-flex

I have a Flex-app.xml. The actual manifest in the apk file seems to be created off of this xml file. I wish to add an intent-filter to the manifest. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that -app.xml file search for intent-filter and you'll find this block (haven't used this myself yet but seems like the right place:

```
<!-- Specify Android specific tags that get passed to AndroidManifest.xml file. -->
<!--<android> 
    <manifestAdditions>
    <![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-configuration android:reqFiveWayNav="true"/>
            <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"/>
            <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>
            <application android:enabled="true">
                <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>
        </manifest>
    ]]>
    </manifestAdditions> 
</android> -->
<!-- End of the schema for adding the android specific tags in AndroidManifest.xml file -->
```